# Remove files and words

Tags: text-processing, grep, awk, xargs

In the moment, when I run `git status`, I got

```
    modified:   loanwolf/alerts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/alerts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/clientspace/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/clientspace/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/configurations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/configurations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/contracts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/contracts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/contrib/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/contrib/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/core/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/core/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/core/templatetags/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/core/templatetags/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/customers/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/customers/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/customers/models.py
    modified:   loanwolf/dashboard/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/dashboard/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/documents/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/documents/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/employees/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/employees/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/equifax_report/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/equifax_report/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/loans/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/loans/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/messaging/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/messaging/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/notes/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/notes/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/operations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/operations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/perception/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/perception/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/products/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/products/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/requests/models.py
    modified:   loanwolf/statistics/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/statistics/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    modified:   loanwolf/users/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
    modified:   loanwolf/users/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

I want to clean the output to remove `modified:` and the files

```
loanwolf/requests/models.py
loanwolf/customers/models.py
loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

In fact, I want to keep all the file except those three last. How could I do that?

For the moment, I think I could do `git status | grep -v 'request'`. I want to `git checkout` all files except those three files.

`git status | grep 'modified:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git [diff|add|checkout]` ??????

Answer (score 2):

It should do the trick:

```
git status | awk '{print $2}' | fgrep -v -f list_to_remove
```

Which the `list_to_remove` content is:

```
loanwolf/requests/models.py
loanwolf/customers/models.py
loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

Comment: git status | grep modified | awk '{print $2}' | fgrep -v -f 'loanwolf/requests/models.py' 'loanwolf/customers/models.py' 'loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po' ?????

Comment: Sorry, but it did not give me what I wanted

Comment: Create a file named: `list_to_remove` save those 3 file name within this file, then run the command exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: Why to put in a file? Do you have another alternative